# MKMapView display route

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

Im pretty new to mkmapview so I'll hope my question will be clear enough.
Let's say I have a code where im saving the userLocation in an array (MKuserLocation type). im saving this for every step the user take and than I want to display this.

How do I do that? how can I use this userlocation with the coordinates that I save and display the path?

***** im adding this after the comment I was told to use MKmapoverlay. does someone can give me an example how to use this with coordinates? or have some guide (I really tried something clear enough on google but didn't)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can make a path from thoses point. You must be careful to to have your array of point in the right order otherwise you will draw lines between point in every direction. you can draw a line with an mkoverlay

Comment: Yes Im saving any update in user location as a new element in array
I'll try to do this with mkoverlay

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue few days ago and I found the sample application on GitHub.you can download the project from [here](https://github.com/kadirpekel/MapWithRoutes).

I hope it will be helpful !!